# Failure when running Eight Schools Example

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymc, pymc3

I tried to run the [Eight Schools Model](http://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/Diagnosing_biased_Inference_with_Divergences.html#The-Eight-Schools-Model) as a simple example. Specifically, the code I'm trying to run is:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

plt.style.use('seaborn-darkgrid')
print('Runing on PyMC3 v{}'.format(pm.__version__))

SEED = [20100425, 20100234]

%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

# Data of the Eight Schools Model
J = 8
y = np.asarray([28,  8, -3,  7, -1,  1, 18, 12], dtype=float)
sigma = np.asarray([15, 10, 16, 11,  9, 11, 10, 18], dtype=float)
# tau = 25.

with pm.Model() as Centered_eight:
    mu = pm.Normal('mu', mu=0, sd=5)
    tau = pm.HalfCauchy('tau', beta=5)
    theta = pm.Normal('theta', mu=mu, sd=tau, shape=J)
    obs = pm.Normal('obs', mu=theta, sd=sigma, observed=y)

with Centered_eight:
    short_trace = pm.sample(600, chains=2, random_seed=SEED)
```

But it fails at the last line, and jupyter notebook gives me this error in CMD):

```
[I 12:25:24.013 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 137bcad0-e823-487d-a9cb-fc48731f5785
[I 12:25:25.136 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 137bcad0-e823-487d-a9cb-fc48731f5785
C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
 55%|███████████████████████████████████████████▏                                  | 609/1100 [00:01<00:01, 336.28it/s]C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1100/1100 [00:02<00:00, 407.71it/s]
Process SpawnPoolWorker-3:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\pool.py", line 360, in get
    racquire()
  File "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
KeyboardInterrupt
  File "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\pool.py", line 360, in get
    racquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
[I 12:26:49.406 NotebookApp] Interrupted...
[I 12:26:49.406 NotebookApp] Shutting down 1 kernel
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
libifcoremd.dll    00007FFD6DEB94C4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNELBASE.dll     00007FFDC0B6717D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FFDC0DC2774  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FFDC38C0D51  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
libifcoremd.dll    00007FFD6DEB94C4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNELBASE.dll     00007FFDC0B6717D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FFDC0DC2774  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FFDC38C0D51  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
libifcoremd.dll    00007FFD6DEB94C4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNELBASE.dll     00007FFDC0B6717D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FFDC0DC2774  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FFDC38C0D51  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
[I 12:26:49.809 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: 137bcad0-e823-487d-a9cb-fc48731f5785
```

I'm able to successfully run two other examples ([linear regression](http://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started.html#A-Motivating-Example:-Linear-Regression) and [the coal mining example](http://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started.html#Case-study-2:-Coal-mining-disasters)), so I thought maybe the `chains` argument in `pm.sample()` might be causing the trouble. If I restart the kernel and run the code without specifying `chains`, then it works. In fact, if I put chains back in, then it still works fine. However, if I start up the kernel and run it with `chains`, then I get that error.

So, I'm able to run the code with chains, but not unless I run without it first. It looks like some caching goes on behind the scenes that lets me do this. What's going on, and is there a way to just run the code without having to do it twice like this?

Comment: Change to `chains=1`